# MVC for the complex structure of classes (in qt c++ audiobookplayer project)

Tags: c++, qt, oop, model-view-controller

I need help.

Everyone knows that MVC and OOP solve a lot of problems, but I can't apply them.

I am writing a program - an audiobook player with Qt C++. I completely use OOP - each class is a small pure black box, has a finished interface with the individual responsibility. And it is easy to work with it and construct it.

For example. the object class **BookView** has only methods for setup the **author** and **title**(that it will show) and useractions signals (e.g. the users desire **to remove the book**).

Similarly, the **Book** object has only the methods to set and get **author** and **title** from the book, and notifications signals of their changes.

There is also a so called **BookController** - thin controller, which connects to the signals of **Book** changes and updates them on **BookView**, as well as and change the model while reacting on **BookView** user signals.

**Here the problem**: Model contains object BookShelf, which has **Book**s objects, each of Book object contains **Chapter** objects (something like folder), **Chapter** object contains **Page** objects (something like files).

Model -> BookShelf -> Book(list) -> Chapter(list) -> Page(list)

The same is true for the views. MainView -> TabView -> ShelfView -> BookView(Table) -> ChapterView(tree) -> PageWidget

So how can thin controller know about it's view (and model)? How do it with OOP, cause each class must not know about others? Cause all objects are blackboxes.

Comment: Your question is too broad for SO which is for specific programming problems. The architecture design aspects might be on topic for programmers.stackexchange.com or a code sample might work on codereview.stackexchange.com. I suggest reading the help sections of those sites to see if you can formulate an on topic question.

Comment: thanks for the answer